# Problema con error 405 en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, http-post, navegador-web, http-get

Tengo un problema al actualizar la pagina, tengo la siguiente interfaz,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando busco un usuario en el filtro, le doy enviar y este carga normalmente, el codigo en este filtro es.

vista.

```html
  <form action="{{route('usuario.ugestion')}}" method="post">
     <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
         <tr><td style="width:50%;" border="0">  
   
                 
                 <input type="text" name="valorgestion" id="valorgestion" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Usuario"></td>
                  
              {{csrf_field()}}
                  <td style="width:50%;" border="1"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>               
            </td></tr>
         </table> 
    </form>
```

Ruta.

```html
Route::post('/panel/gestion', 'CuentaController@ugestion')->name('usuario.ugestion');
```

y el metodo.

```html
   public function ugestion(Request $request)
    {
        $registrado = \Auth::user()->tipos_usuarios_id;

            if($registrado == 1)

           {

               $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);
               $valorgestion = (int)$request->valorgestion;
               $userstarea=user::where("username","=",$request->valorgestion)->paginate(6);
               $userstarea->appends(['valorgestion'=>$valorgestion]);
               $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::where('asignacion', NULL)->pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
               $conteo=user::where("username","=",$request->valorgestion)->count();
               return view('usuario.tareas')->with(["userstarea" => $userstarea, "usuariosOpciones" => $usuariosOpciones, "conteo" => $conteo]);
               
           }
      
    }
```

Como pueden ver todo lo tengo configurando por post, por lo tanto despues de cargado el resultado si selecciono la url y doy enter me aparece un error 405 de metod not allowed, si en vez de post pongo todo en get pues esto no pasa, pero no quiero dejar get, hay alguna manera de evitar esto?

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo: «después de cargado el resultado, si selecciono la url y doy enter, me aparece un error 405», ¿en dónde seleccionas la url? ¿en dónde das enter?

Comment: Si amigo, borre las caches en php artisan y pues la ruta esta bien, bueno, pues me consulta lo que quiero, yo la tengo asi.             Route::post('/panel/gestion', 'CuentaController@ugestion')->name('usuario.ugestion');

Comment: Si shaz, arriba en el navegador, donde esta el cuadro en rojo, si selecciono la url actual y doy enter para actualizar la pagina, ahi es donde me arroja un error 405, esto es con post, por que si paso la ruta y el formulario a get esto no pasa, pero la necesito dejar con post

Comment: Pues es normal que aparezca un 405, al dar enter en el campo de la url del navegador se genera un GET.

Comment: pues.. no se, es como si al dar enter llamara al metodo, pero sin mandarle parametros, el caso es.. eso normal entonces? o se puede evitar?

Comment: Para resumirlo: «es normal», de hecho es casi una miniprotección y sería un poco más inseguro si no funcionara así. Te invito por favor a leer sobre los verbos HTTP y como los utiliza Laravel o cualquier otro framework o lenguaje. Es un concepto básico que todo programador debe dominar, en Google se encuentra fácilmente suficiente información.

Comment: Bueno Shaz gracias, leere muy bien lo que dices... ahora entiendo.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no hay ningún problema por resolver.

Comment: siempre podes poner un manejador get ( ademas del post ) que redireccione a un index onda `Route::get('/panel/gestion', 'CuentaController@index')`

Comment: Si voy a borrar esto.. pero saben hay algo que me parece curioso, cuando doy clic en el circulo de actualizar no pasa nada, es solo cuando doy enter en la url, por que no pasara nada con el boton de actualizar?

Comment: El botón actualizar normalmente realiza (de nuevo) o intenta realizar la última acción efectuada al momento de llegar a la url actual, mientras que desde la barra del navegador se genera un GET directamente. Por favor elimina la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**El comportamiento descrito por el OP es normal y no hay ningún error en lo planteado en esta pregunta.**

---

Voy a describir lo que está haciendo el OP:

1. Definir una ruta POST en Laravel
2. Acceder a dicha ruta correctamente (probablemente a través de un formulario)
3. Ir a la barra de navegación (donde se escribe la URL) del navegador y presionar Enter

En ese orden de ideas es normal que aparezca un error 405, puesto que es una ruta POST y se está intentando acceder por medio de GET, por lo cual dicho método no está permitido.

---

Para intentar guiar al OP y a los futuros visitantes, aquí un extracto tomado de MDN:

> Cada vez que desee llegar a un recurso en la Web, el navegador envía una petición a una URL. Una petición HTTP consta de dos partes: un encabezado que contiene un conjunto de metadatos globales sobre las capacidades del navegador, y un cuerpo que puede contener la información necesaria para que el servidor pueda procesar la petición específica.
>
> **El método GET**
>
> El método GET es  utilizado por el navegador para pedir al servidor que se envíe de vuelta un recurso dado: "Hey servidor, quiero obtener este recurso." En este caso, el navegador envía un cuerpo vacío.